# SVG hosted cuts out on Chrome but it works in Opera browser and local host (Obviously is not working on Internet Explorer either)

Tags: html, css, svg, host

This is a bit weird as I was working with Google Chrome developer tools(on the hosted page) and looks like my SVG has got the property overflow:hidden instead of 'showing' that is declared on my CSS. Another thing is the tooltip is not working and like I said everything is fine in Opera.

This is the SVG code in my HTML:

```
<svg

   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="70%"
   height="70%"
   preserveAspectRatio="x200Y200 meet"
   viewBox="0 0 350 350"
   id="svg2"
   sodipodi:docname="newSVG2.svg"
>
  <metadata
     id="metadata3927">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <sodipodi:namedview

     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     id="namedview3925"
     showgrid="false"
     showguides="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.79719298"
     inkscape:cx="100%"
     inkscape:cy="100%"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="Water" />
  <defs
     id="defs48">
    <clipPath
       id="clipPath2863">
      <rect
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         x="0"
         y="39.163246"
         id="rect2865" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath
       id="clipPath2867">
      <rect
         width="100%"
         height="100%"
         x="0"
         y="39.163246"
         id="rect2869" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g class=map
     transform="matrix(1,0,0,1.6,0,-62.661196)"
     id="Districts">

    <path class="HI-map niihau" data-tooltip="tooltip1" 
       d="m 753.82226,356.57637 0,0.23996 0,0.23995 0,0.23996 -0.23999,0.23996 -0.24,0 -0.71998,0 -0.47999,0 -0.23999,0 -0.24,0.23995 -0.23999,0 -0.47999,0 -0.24,0 -0.95997,0.23996 -0.24,0 0,-0.23996 -0.23999,0 0,-0.23995 -0.47999,0 0,-0.47992 -0.23999,0 0,-0.23995 -0.47999,0 -0.47999,0 0,0.23995 0,0.23996 -0.24,0 -0.71998,0
```

and so on with the coords...

This is my project URL hosted: 
http://cristianramon.co.uk/mapscoord/#map

This is what Chrome shows me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMl3V.jpg)

and this is what Opera shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwLYG.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Please ensure the code in the question is a [mcve]. We should not need to use links to access your question data. The current code in the question is incomplete as it does not have an overflow attribute, does not demonstrate the issue and is not minimal.

Comment: Based on a photo it looks like you didn't set the dimensions correctly. I had this problem before. Opera show correctly but Mozilla didn't. Instead of width="70%" try using some pixel values and check if it solves the problem. (Shouldn't this value be used only for pixel dimensions?) I always remove width/height from svg and apply it as external css.

Comment: Thanks for yours answers. Apparently it was a bug, I just opened my project 3 days after to host it and works fine!